# How to get the id of closest input text without jquery?

Tags: javascript

Doing my project in IE 7 (unfortunately). I have this DOM where I want to know the ID of the closest input text that is positioned after the button I clicked, not the input text before it. Here's the example DOM:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<br/>
<button>Get ID</button>
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<br/>
```

I know how to do it in Jquery but does someone know how to do it the 'hard' way (if possible)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy if they're always siblings like that.

```
var nextInputId = buttonClicked.nextSibling.id;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V69jN/).

This is fragile and not recommended for anything but a very simple set of limited markup.

Unfortunately, `nextElementSibling` isn't available until IE9, so if you have a text node there (even some whitespace), you're in for some pain.

A pretty good solution that is relatively robust would be...

```
var node = buttonClicked;
var nextInputId = null;

while (node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
        nextInputId = node.id;
        break;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uLsp/).

Comment: But what if there's an element with an ID in between the button and the next input text? I also thought about nextSibling using it in a for loop.

Comment: @itagomo Then use the second example. If it must be `input[type="text"]`, then check for that too.

Comment: Got it. but any idea how to find out if the next input is `type="text"` ?

Comment: @itagomo `input.type == "text"`.

Comment: `this` is not working in IE 7. What I did is `document.activeElement` but not getting the result that I want. Looks like the loop stops on the first element between the button and the input text tag.